# Is it possible to Moq two different Api POST calls by parameter

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, dotnet-httpclient

I want to mock the calls to an external Api, and trying to test the code when a valid Id is passed to that endpoint and when it isn't.
The problems I see are two:

- The Api call is a Post and the parameter I'm interested on is passed
  as a StringContent.
- In my application, all the mocks are together in
  a extension class.

So my test class has a method for checking that the main process is working:

```cs
[Test]
public async Task ShouldReturnOKForAValidDocument()
{
    var request = new GetInfoQuery(1);
    var result = await SendAsync(request);

    Assert.NotNull(result);
    Assert.True(result.IsSuccess);
}
```

The part where the Api is called is like:

```cs
    var serialized = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new { documentId = Id });
    var stringContent = new StringContent(serialized, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, stringContent, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

And there's a Mock for that Api call:

```cs
private static void MockApiCalls(Mock<HttpMessageHandler> mock) {
...
    mock.Protected()
            .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("SendAsync", ItExpr.Is((HttpRequestMessage e) => e.Method.Method == "POST"
                && e.RequestUri.ToString().Contains("/api/GetDocInfo")), ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
            .ReturnsAsync(DocInfoResponse);

}
```

I wonder if it could be possible to add a restriction on the mock that checks for the parameter documentId being 1, and thus creating another mock for an invalid Id, like -1 and being able to also check for invalid document responses.

Comment: Yeah using callbacks where you go read the request body and deserialize it again. But then you'll just be writing your own code in reverse again, you now have double the maintenance and what have you proven?

Comment: And that's a good point.

Comment: I don't see the problem here. Create two separate test cases. One for the happy path ( `documentId` is `1`)  and other for the unhappy path (`documentId` is `-1`). In each test case you can define the appropriate mocked response separately.

Comment: @PeterCsala As I commented on the PO, the Mocks aren't defined on the test themselves. It is done like this because there is more preparation involved for the project that depends on it. And I can't change it.

Comment: Can you change/amend the `MockApiCalls` method?

Comment: @PeterCsala Yes. But remember it is on a common class and it's called by "Testing.cs"